# dynamic sql with datekey

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL, however I would like to add a date key to this but been struggling: SQL as follows

```
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(100) = 'dbo'
        DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
        IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Nulls') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Nulls

        CREATE TABLE #Nulls (DataBaseName sysname,SchemaName sysname,TableName sysname, ColumnName sysname, 
        ColumnPosition     int 
        , NullCount int , NonNullCount int)


        select @sql += 'select DBName = '''+ quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) 
        +''',SchemaName = '''+ quotename(table_schema) +''',TableName = '''
        + quotename(table_name) + ''' , ColumnName = ''' + quotename(column_name) 
        + ''' , ColumnPosition = ''' + convert(varchar(5) , ordinal_position) 
        + ''' , CountNulls = sum(case when ' + quotename(column_name) + ' is null  
        then 1 else 0 end) , CountnonNulls = count(' + quotename(column_name) + ') 
        from ' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ';' + char(10)

        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema AND (@Table IS NULL OR TABLE_NAME = @Table)

        INSERT INTO #Nulls 
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql

        SELECT *,NullCntPercentage = (case when isnull(NullCount,0)=0 then 0 else cast((NullCount*100.0/(NullCount+NonNullCount)) as decimal(15,2)) end) 
        ,NonNullCntPercentage = (case when NonNullCount=0 then 0 else cast((NonNullCount*100.0/(NullCount+NonNullCount)) as decimal(15,2)) end)
        FROM #Nulls order by TableName,ColumnPosition
```

I would like to add the date key using the following

```
 convert(nvarchar(11),getdate(),112)
```

But been struggling to add this to dynamic sql and not in the output in the second stage which does the percentage

Thank you

Comment: Add a datekey to where? Do you mean in the #Nulls table? If so, could you not just add a column of type `DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE());`?

Comment: Yes thats an idea I just thought about now actually,  it's just come to me literally couple of mins ago ,  but just wondering just for my understanding how this can be embedded in the dynamic sql to put into target table by adding a column you mentioned

Comment: Um, if you want it stored as a datetime instead of varchar, you could just add getdate() to the dynamic sql (e.g. after adding the column in the creation of the #nulls table, just add `, getdate()` before `from`. If you wanted to store it as varchar, then just add `convert(nvarchar(11),getdate(),112)` instead of `getdate()`. I think it's better to store it as a datetime, though.